# Delete the last row in a table SQLite android

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am developing an android app where I want to delete the last row in one of my database table. I have tried the code below, but its throwing a syntax error.

```
 public void deletelatestprofilefromsystemsettings()
{
    String maxid = System_id + "="+"SELECT MAX ("+System_id+") FROM" +TABLE_SYSTEM_SETTINGS;
    getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_SYSTEM_SETTINGS, maxid ,null);
}
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: which error, and where? Sorry, I'm not the telepathist...

Answer (score 1):

You are lacking a space after the FROM, and subqueries must be written in parentheses:

```java
String maxid = System_id + "=" +
               "(SELECT MAX("+System_id+") FROM " + TABLE_SYSTEM_SETTINGS + ")";
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to execute a DELETE with a SELECT in the same query. AFAIK you shouldn't do it. You have to execute the SELECT query first, in order to retrieve the desired id, then execute the deletion. In other words, execute `Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().query()`, read the id from the cursor, then use it in `getWritableDatabase().delete()`.

Also, add a space after `") FROM"`, so it becomes `") FROM "` in order to avoid a syntax error.

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX ("+System_id+") FROM " +TABLE_SYSTEM_SETTINGS, null);
  getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_SYSTEM_SETTINGS, cursor.getString(0) ,null);

Comment: Not bad, although I think `MAX(column)` returns a numeric value and not a string. Also I would store `cursor.getString(0)` (or `cursor.getInt(0)` for that matter) in a separate variable and perform `cursor.close()` immediately aftewards.

Comment: There is no problem with a SELECT in a subquery of a DELETE.